# A simple and general way to handle all Netty asynchronous outbound exceptions without calling sync() or adding listeners for each operation?

Tags: exception, netty

In Netty we usually call methods on a `Channel` or a `ChannelHandlerContext` to  perform operations on the connection. Especially methods such as `write()`, `flush()`, and `writeAndFlush()` are used to send messages. However, these methods are asynchronous and they can raise exceptions if there are errors in the connection or in the passed parameters. Such exceptions are not handled unless we call `sync()`/`get()` to wait for the result synchronously, or add listeners using `addListener()`/`addListeners()`.

So my question is: is there a general method to handle all such exceptions asynchronously without calling extra methods, for example, by adding an overall exception handler during building the `Bootstrap` or initializing the `Channel`?

I have read  and tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31073723/5082913, but found that adding the `ChannelDuplexHandler` at the tail of the pipeline can only handle inbound exceptions.

Comment: Would `.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.FIRE_EXCEPTION_ON_FAILURE)` be too much code you you?

Comment: I didn't know there was a method like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of coding your listener yourself,  you should use pre-existing listeners that already deal with exceptions

Just call `.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.FIRE_EXCEPTION_ON_FAILURE)` after every write/flush call

Exceptions thrown during sending will now be channeled to your `exceptionCaught(Throwable ex)` function, so you can deal with write and read exceptions in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative for `.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.FIRE_EXCEPTION_ON_FAILURE)` is to pass `ctx.voidPromise()` as the 2nd argument of `write` or `writeAndFlush`. It will take care of propagating exceptions. An additional benefit it that unused ChannelFuture objects won't get created.

Example:

```
ctx.write(msg, ctx.voidPromise());
```

Comment: Similar answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9030420